# text containing emails but no space between words.How to extract emails

Tags: python, regex

I have a text containing only emails but there is no space between 
each email

Example : `email1@file1.comemail2@file1.comemail3@dom1.net`

I have applied `re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', str(line))` and this is what I got

```
email1@file1.comemail
2@file1.comemail
3@dom1.net
```

Popular tlds are `.com`,`.net`,`.info`,`.org`. So if I find one of them after `@[\w\.-]+` then I will induce a space after the tlds in the line and then extract email.

But how to check it I have .com or.net or .info ....

Comment: Perhaps using a non greedy match and list the options for .com and .net `[^@]+?@[^@]+?\.(?:com|net)` https://regex101.com/r/xcUXc4/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (which can become quite cumbersome if you take a lot of variations into account like .com .net etc..) could be to use a non greedy `+?` match and list all the options that you would allow using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
[\w.-]+?@[\w.-]+?\.(?:com|net)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqGIFa/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eL4NNb)

**Note** that repeating the character class `[\w.-]+` would also allow for example `.-.-.@.-.-..com`

For example

```
import re
s = "email1@file1.comemail2@file1.comemail3@dom1.net"
regex = r"[\w.-]+?@[\w.-]+?\.(?:com|net)"
res = re.findall(regex, s)
print(res)
```

Result

```
['email1@file1.com', 'email2@file1.com', 'email3@dom1.net']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` to add space after each tlds. As an example I specified `.net`, `.org` and `.com`, but you can add as many as you want.

Then you can apply your regex

```
import re   
text = 'email1@file1.comemail2@file1.comemail3@dom1.net'
new_text = re.sub(r'(.com|.net|.org)', r'\1 ', text)
emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', new_text)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['email1@file1.com', 'email2@file1.com', 'email3@dom1.net']
```